# Wcf Friend Assemblies on iis, not working at runtime

Tags: wcf, iis, naming, internalsvisibleto

i have a problem regarding InternalsVisibleTo.

I have an Assembly named **A** with an internal test class
I have a Wcf Service (**WcfService1**) hosted on **iis** that is referencing this assembly via static linking (add reference on visual studio).

i have the **A** - *AssemblyInfo.cs* file with:

```
[assembly: InternalsVisibleTo("WcfService1")]
```

I build and add the **A.dll** to the WcfService1. 
Obviously, on **WcfService1** class, i call the internal method of the **A.dll**, and the *intellisense*  signal me correctly the name of the method, the variables etc.

It compile smoothly and no problem is shown.

however, when i build and run on his, the server give me a compilation error:

**CS0122 'method called' is inaccessible due to its protection level**

so i'm confused: in the Visual Studio IDE i got correctly the autocompletion and no build errors. When run, it cannot use the internal methods?!

Other info: i tried with **Strong naming** and **without**(public key calculated via command prompt), with the same result (on IDE is ok, when run it crash).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution.

I was calling the internal method from the method initialize() of the IIS.

This method is used to do inizialization, and the class with initialize() must be placed in App_Code folder.

I moved the offending call to another class, in my friend assembly, et voilà, problem solved :) hope it will help someone!